# Foot X Ray: Oblique vs Lateral View - Terminology points to Same or different?

Tags: bone-fractures, x-rays, legs, barefoot

Foot X Ray: Oblique vs Lateral View - Same or different?

> Side note / prelude to question:
>
> So I am currently in a high Covid city in Asia and its Sunday.
>
> I‘be been already advised to get an AP & Oblique view x rays done.
>
> I came across this terminology mix up because of the following.
>
> I am trying to book appointment via apps / websites for Monday and AP
> view is clear and some Radio Labs seem to call it Lateral View, Some
> Oblique View and some aggregator apps have both in options.

Even when I google each separately or together, based on what I got I am not sure if they are same w 2 names or different.

**This is a question on medical terminology used by various different entities; this is not to ask medical advise.

Are they same or different? I am just more confused as the verbiage is all over and unclear.**

https://musculoskeletalkey.com/radiology-in-foot-and-ankle/

https://radiopaedia.org/articles/foot-medial-oblique-view-1

https://www.apma.org/files/Evans_Daniel_AM_Assistants%27%20Program.pdf

https://www.aliem.com/emrad-foot-x-ray/

Comment: Whoever recommended the x-ray being done might be able to help you solve this question.

Comment: @thomas - It’s a legit medical query on labels used for a view; interchangeably on various medical sites online. They were kind enough to take time out on Sunday and  and won’t be accessible. I’ve to do this online via websites/ apps - so clarity on terminology being used would be a valid question here

Comment: The validity of the question is not the issue. You cannot ask for personal medical advice, and it seems without this being an emergency you may be best served asking your personal physician in charge of this case.

Comment: Remove the personal element. It’s an objective question about terminology being used to eliminate ambiguity in usage by medical organisations & people. Let’s focus on that.

Comment: I’ve not asked for personal medical advise. I got my medical advise. Sometimes different places and people in medical world use different terms or mixed ones. This is to clear that. Simple. I’ve seen tons of times medical stuff like that; it varies from US, UK to Asia. Such is the world.

Comment: Please edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your first reference points out the difference between a lateral ankle view versus an oblique view. The oblique view is taken from a lateral position but the joint is tilted so that the rays travel parallel to the joint surface. Otherwise, a lateral view results in superimposition of different parts of the joint being imaged rendering it unclear.